# Missing tesseract50.dll from conda installation

Tags: python, conda, tesseract, conda-forge

I have a Windows 11 64x computer with a new conda env created. I installed tesseract from conda using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tesseract
```

Before the 5.0 release, a file called `tesseract41.dll` was created in `env_name\Library\bin`, along with the tesseract exe. Now with the release of tesseract 5.0, I can't find the file `tesseract50.dll`. What I do see is a file called `tesseract50.lib` in `env_name\Library\lib`.

I can use tesseract from the command line normally. However, I'm trying to use the API in Python, so can't use the lib file as `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` doesn't detect it as a valid app.

I can´t use libraries such as PyTesseract, because it is too slow, and I can't use tesserocr as it doesn't support Python 3.10, and the wheels are outdated, so I need to build my own wrapper.

**QUESTION**

How can I get the `tesseract50.dll` file without having to build tesseract from source or install it from binaries?

Comment: Probably best to raise this here: https://github.com/conda-forge/tesseract-feedstock/issues

Comment: Agree with cle, looks like a decision was made to have a static instead of dynamic library in the conda-forge package. Do you have a c compiler installed? You could write your own little c wrapper that creates a dll that exposes the tesseract functions you need.